How to combine ◌̑ and ι in Microsoft Word?
I am trying to replicate a word from a lexicon. It is

But for a 5th char, I did not find the unicode.
Does it even exist?
Or is there a way to combine those two unicode chars from the title in Word?

This is a use for Combining Diacritical Marks
The easiest way to go about it is using the Character map tool. Press the Windows key, type char and run the character map tool. The character you are looking for is number 311, a Combining Inverted Breve.
You can then copy the character and insert it before your ι symbol to get ̑ι.
Supposedly you are also meant to be able to insert it using Alt codes.
There are some answers at Quora but most of them seem to boil down to using a keyboard with the correct diacritics already in use.

Thanks, I managed to write ι̑

type "greek" as search item in charmap? (works in Ubuntu "characters")

Although the diacritical mark resembles an inverted breve in the typeface that's used for the text in your image, it's actually a circumflex (perispomeni). In other typefaces, this diacritical resembles ^ or ~.
The comining form of the diacritical is Unicode 0342. (A lowercase iota + a circumflex also exists as a single character in Unicode; the code is 1fd6.)

"In Ancient Greek grammar, a perispomenon (περισπώμενον) is a word with a high-low pitch contour on the last syllable, indicated in writing by a tilde diacritic (◌̃) or an inverted breve accent mark (◌̑) in native transcriptions with the Greek alphabet, or by a circumflex accent mark (◌̂) in transcriptions with the Latin alphabet. A properispomenon has the same kind of accent, but on the penultimate syllable." From wikipedia. I do believe that what the image shows is an inverted breve.

@VincentDesrosiers. Incorrect. The wikipedia article is merely describing the different shapes that the diacritical can take. One of those shapes happens to resemble an inverted breve, which has different meaning and is a separate Unicode character. If you're interested in the using the character that's actually correct (not merely the one that looks like what's shown in the image), that character is U 0342. To my knowledge, an inverted breve, properly speaking (i.e., as the distinct Unicode character), has no use at all in ancient or modern Greek, not even in epigraphical transcription.

I see, interesting. I was not aware there was an unicode specifically called perispomeni. Thanks for bringing that to my attention, will use
